# How to view in Logcat the logs of a JAR library included in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, logging

I have many `'System.out.println("some log to print");'` statements in a JAR that I included in my Android project. But I am not able to see the logs in Logcat.

1- I would like to know if there is a way to output those print statements in Logcat or in a terminal without adding a logging library into my JAR?

2- If what I ask is impossible, what would you recommend as a logging library? [log4j](http://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/)?

Thanks for any help on this,

Comment: please try to reset adb.

Comment: Also, please use `android.util.Log` for Android-specific logging. While `System.out.println()` is supposed to route to LogCat, it is conceivable that it might not in some devices.

Comment: logcat with no filters - such as command-line `adb logcat` with further arguments - will show all that is actually going into the logging system.